# lua ignore stdin error in a loop

Tags: lua, i2c

I am trying to give start on all addresses on the bus, Just to see the list of devices on the bus. The call to `i2c.start()` fails and the control comes out of loop:

```
>for i=1,127 do
>> if i2c.start(i) == nil then
>> print(i)
>> end
>> end
>
```

It prints:

```
stdin:2: i2c 1 does not exist
```

Is there a way to do this in Lua?

Comment: Not sure about i2c, but from general principles you want to wrap `i2c.start` in pcall.

Comment: Have you defined `i2c` previously in the interactive session as local ?